# HTML link opening wrong page

Tags: html

I’m new to HTML and web design. I’m trying to open a page called “register.html” in the same directory as the current page using a link wrapped around a button. However, everytime i click the button, a page I am not requesting, called “registered.html” is trying to be accessed instead and the console throws an error as shown below.

Can someone please explain why a different link is trying to be opened instead of the one I’m asking the button to open? Thank you.

Code excerpt:

```
   <form method = "get" action = "registered.html"> 
          <a href ="Register.html"><button type = "submit"  class = "registerAsButton1">Customer</button></a>
          <a href ="Register.html"><button type = "submit"  class = "registerAsButton2">Vendor</button></a>
                            
                           
         <a href="index3.html" class = "link1">ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT? SIGN IN</a>
                        
            
     </form>
```

Console error:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///Users/betramlalusha/Desktop/vendor's%20Corner/registered.html?

Comment: You have a button inside a link. If you click the button, it submits the form which action is defined as `registered.html` . Never put buttons inside links, this can lead to confusing results. Either you have a link OR a button, never both at the same time.

Comment: Or change the button type to `button` from `submit`

Comment: Simply running the markup through the validator would have pointed out these errors to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I also found that adding « e.preventDefault() » in my JavaScript file worked as well. I have a lot to learn haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all be sure that you are using the latest version of browser. Then be sure if your files are in the html css folder which folder you are using for edit. if it isnt stopped I would suggest you to reset your ide or reinstall your ide for the better experience other wise it should be opened. Thank you.